# Render value from List only once Vue 3

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3

I am using `v-for` to render everything from JSON List with Vue. I have JSON file of following structure:

```
{
  "Cards": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "TITLE",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum",
      "price": "2500",
      "services": [
        {
          "icons": [
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "male",
              "tooltip": "Maximum number of people",
              "after": "2"
            },
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "bed",
              "tooltip": "Number of beds",
              "after": "2 + (side bed)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "icons": [
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "coffee",
              "tooltip": "Services",
              "after": "TV, Wi-Fi, parking"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TITLE",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum",
      "price": "3200",
      "services": [
        {
          "icons": [
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "female",
              "tooltip": "Maximum number of people",
              "after": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my current structure for rendering:

```
<div v-for="(card, index) in Cards" :key="index">
  <div>
    <template v-for="(icons, icon_ids) in card.services" :key="icon_ids">
      <div>
        <template v-for="(icon, icon_idx) in icons.icons" :key="icon_idx">
          <div>
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="[icon.pre, icon.icon]"/>
            <span>{{icon.after}}
              <sup v-if="icon.sup != null">{{icon.sup}}</sup>
            </span>
            <span class="tip-inner">{{ icon.tooltip }}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:**
By this all my `icons` from `services` renderes twice in each card. On first card should be only `man`, `bed`, `coffee` and on the other card should be `woman` but... All of the are at both cards.

[image: Error picture]

So `Cards` with `id: 0` would have two icons and `id: 1` would have only one icon.
How can I make to render `services` only for the card they are under?

**EDIT 2:** (**Solution**)
Everything works perfectly like this... I just made mistake and had another `v-for` above the component which created my mistake. This code I posted here is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahoj Šimon,

Can you clarify what the issue is? Seems to be working ok (although I used `fontawesome` without `vue-fontawesome`, maybe `:icon="[icon.pre, icon.icon]"` is giving you unexpected results.)

```js
const Cards = [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "TITLE",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum",
      "price": "2500",
      "services": [
        {
          "icons": [
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "male",
              "tooltip": "Maximum number of people",
              "after": "2"
            },
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "bed",
              "tooltip": "Number of beds",
              "after": "2 + (side bed)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "icons": [
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "coffee",
              "tooltip": "Services",
              "after": "TV, Wi-Fi, parking"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TITLE",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum",
      "price": "3200",
      "services": [
        {
          "icons": [
            {
              "pre": "fas",
              "icon": "female",
              "tooltip": "Maximum number of people",
              "after": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    return {
        Cards
    }
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

```css
.card{display:block; border: 1px solid black;padding:8px;margin:8px;border-radius:4px;}
.icon{font-size: 1em; color: Tomato; min-width:30px;display:inline-block;text-align:center;}
.tip-inner{color:#aaa;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(card, index) in Cards" :key="index" class="card">
  <div>
    <template v-for="(icons, icon_ids) in card.services" :key="icon_ids">
      <div>
        <template v-for="(icon, icon_idx) in icons.icons" :key="icon_idx">
          <div>
            <span class="icon"><i :class="icon.pre + ' fa-' + icon.icon"></i></span>
            <span>{{icon.after}}
              <sup v-if="icon.sup != null">{{icon.sup}}</sup>
            </span>
            <span class="tip-inner">{{ icon.tooltip }}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```